# Docx4J Open XML

Tags: docx4j

I am reading some .docx files with Docx4J which contains hyperlinks.

I am getting URLs while clicking on those hyperlinks manually but when i am trying to read those file with Docx4J  i am getting only text  nothing about those Hyperlinks and URLs.

Document Text -

Infosys Chairman, KV Kamath said that IT services were facing challenges of scalability. Speaking at the 31st Annual General Meeting of the company in Bangalore, Kamath said the management has met all the challenges successfully and demonstrated leadership. Infosys, India's second largest IT services company announced a final dividend of Rs 22/share. The company also announced a special dividend of Rs 10/share on account of the 10th year of operations of the Infosys BPO. Speaking at the AGM, S D Shibulal, CEO of Infosys said that transformation is complete and the company is now focussed on growth. "Infosys 3.0 will help company address challenges," said Shibulal. Shibulal said: "We had a choice between commoditization and re-defining the industry. We chose to redefine the industry."..[more](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/tech/ites/infosys-to-focus-on-growth-announces-final-dividend-of-rs-22/share/articleshow/13966323.cms)

Hyperlink is on "more"

Docx4J is giving the text 'more' only. It is not giving information regarding that hyperlink.

Is there any way how to get that URL??

Please Help...

Comment: How are you getting the text? You should probably edit this question to include your code and the OpenXML representing the hyperlink.  I expect you'll find the hyperlink contains a relId, and that relationship contains the URL you are looking for. So you have to get the relationship...

Comment: Post what the answer was.

Comment: I'm using the latest docx4j (3.3.6) and there is no problem reading hyperlinks.